# If the restriction of $f$ to every line parallel to a coordinate axis has bounded variation, then does $f$ have bounded variation?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, bounded-variation

Let $f : K \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function for some open cube $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with edges parallel to the coordinate axes. Suppose that $f \vert_{K \cap L}$ is of bounded variation for every line $L$ that is parallel to a coordiante axis. Is it true that $f$ has bounded variation on $K$?

This isn't a set exercise; I don't know if it's true or not.

Comment: Are you assuming $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Is $K$ specifically an open cube in $\Bbb R^3$, or is it in an arbitrary finite dimension?

Comment: Good points: I'm willing to assume f is continuous. General dimension n. Do you have reason to believe the dimension matters?

Comment: @Thompson I don't have any real reason to believe that the dimension matters, as long as $n > 1$, but you said "cube", so I wanted to make sure ("cube" is used about arbitrary dimensions too, so it wasn't wrong, it just made me uncertain).

Comment: You can assemble the BV semi-norm from the 1d BV semi-norms along *all* line sections (all directions). [This article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/01630560902841161) gives a proof.

Comment: What does "total variation" mean for a multivariate function?